# How to add a popup menu to the default toolbar?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, toolbar

Is there a way to customize the default toolbar in Mathematica 13? I would like to add a new icon to the toolbar, which triggers a popup menu containing several frontend operations I can customize (such as tagging cells and inserting automatic numberings). I imagine its behavior should be similar to the hyperlink icon:

[image]

Comment: The current toolbar does not support end user customizations. We know there is a good amount of interest in that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid we can't do that. However your need may be met in some other ways.

---

### Why I feel it impossible

Mathematica provided a menu item placed in the menu `Window/Toolbar`. This item is parallel to `Ruler` etc., these items are toggled by several `FrontEndToken`s, while their neighborhoods `Templating` and `Testing` are `DockedCells` toggled by `KernelExecute`. In fact, these menu items change the absence of `"MultipurposeBar"` element in the notebook option `WindowToolbars`.

This seems to imply that this toolbar is a raw Qt frontend object, instead of something represented and controlled by a WL expression.

---

### What can you do

For a customized menu, you can try adding you own `DockedCells`(by `SetOptions`) or integrating your buttons into the menubar(by modifying `MenuSetup.tr`).

The former way is usually preferred if you want this utility to be limited in some notebooks instead of be a global setting. WRI's `Package.nb` creates `DockedCells` in stylesheets, template notebooks set this option for each specific notebook.)

IMO, an advantage of the latter way is that you can have a keyboard shortcut with a better performance(compared to `FrontEndEventActions`).

The WL funciton for menus is `ActionMenu`, while its box representation is `ActionMenuBox`. With some knowledge of cell/box and proper `Appearance` option, you can easily achieve your goal.

BTW, WRI also provides palletes for such things. However I often feel those extra windows disturbing.